# kafka-avro-console-consumer: Specify truststore location for schema-registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, truststore, confluent-schema-registry, java-security

I am using confluent kafka-avro-console-consumer like following

```
/kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server <brokers> --topic Topic-out --property schema.registry.url=https://schemaregistry:443/ --consumer.config client-sasl-ssl.properties  --from-beginning
```

It fails to connect to schema registry with the following error,

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 45
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
```

which means that i need to specify truststore location in java path like ( i have done it for custom java code and it worked)

```
Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks --Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass
```

The question is where do i specify above parameters while running kafka-avro-console-consumer  command.

Comment: Fixed it by using the following export 

```export SCHEMA_REGISTRY_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tools/confluent-5.3.0/bin/kafka.client.truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

export SCHEMA_REGISTRY_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tools/confluent-5.3.0/bin/kafka.client.truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to client-sasl-ssl.properties should fix the problem:

```
schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location=TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION
schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password=TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).